# node js displaying a 2d array as grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, 2d, conways-game-of-life

here is the code for making a 2d array to be used as a board for conways game of life in node.js. i am having a problem with displaying the board. the output looks like this.

```
['-','-','-'] 
['-','-','-']
['-','-','-']
```

however i want it to look like this

```
---
---
---
```

this is the code right now. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
var createBoard = (width, height) => {
    board = [];
    row = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            row.push("-");
        }
        board.push(row);
        row =[];
    }
    return (board);
}

var displayBoard = (board) =>{
    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        console.log(board[i]);
    }
}

gameBoard = createBoard(3,3);
displayBoard(gameBoard);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the elements of the array to form a string.

```js
var createBoard = (width, height) => {
    board = [];
    row = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            row.push("-");
        }
        board.push(row);
        row = [];
    }
    return (board);
}

var displayBoard = (board) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        console.log(board[i].join(""));
    }
}

gameBoard = createBoard(3, 3);
displayBoard(gameBoard);
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue you should iterate over the array and add it to a string, like this:

```
var displayBoard = (board) =>{
   var buffer = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < board[i].length; x++) {
        buffer += board[i][x];
      }
      buffer += '\n';
   }
   console.log(buffer);
}
```

This should print it like this:

```
---
---
---
```